# Document Libraries

Tags: document-library

I am trying to alter the structure to an existing SharePoint site but cannot seem to find a way to move document libraries around.

If you have a look at the attached screenshot, you can see there are a number of folders that "appear" to be in the Accounts folder.

As an example, how would I move say, HR as an example, so that it appears under the Accounts document library?

Cheers [image]

Answer (score 1):

You are merely talking about the Quick Launch Navigation.  No site structure needs to be modified.

Go into Site Settings and under Look and Feel, find either Quick Launch or Navigation>>Current Navigation and adjust the order/hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind guys, got it sorted.

Turns out you can make the changes real easy using the Edge browser!! Why Microsoft don't allow you to do the same with Internet Explorer I have no idea, but I just had an idea to try Edge and it worked!

Thanks for the input anyway :) Consider this matter closed.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot has links that are shown in the left navigation. When your actually on the document library see the views found in the ribbon to learn more about what was set up. Site owners who have permissions to modify the navigation can actually create links to existing views or any web page into the sites navigation. As far as moving files around I would recommend using the "Open with Windows Explorer" option. Hopefully you have the permissions to modify each view bound to your library to learn what is displaying in each view and if there are any filters used to help organize things. As for moving your files use Windows Explorer.

Open With Explorer button:
[image]

Comment: I'll have a look. I'm sure I tried that earlier and it didn't work. When I look at it within Explorer, everything looks like just a normal bunch of folders. 

So, the folders you see in my screenshot which "appear" to be in accounts, are not actually in Accounts when you look at it using Explorer. 

I have been trying all day to figure out how to alter the existing structure, but the answer seems to be evading me.

Comment: You may want to inspect the links you have in the sites left navigation to find out where they are going. Examples: (site/library/folder/file OR Site/Library/LibraryView) The path will help you figure out where the links are going and if the libraries are even on the same site. If they are different libraries the URL's will show it. (site/Library1 vs. site/Library2)

Comment: First you need to figure out how many document libraries are used on the site then you can add/remove them from the site navigation. I learned long ago to never completely trust what was placed in the site navigation as it can be links to anything and it can be organized in many ways.